# Require is not defined with selenium webdriver and broswersify does not appear to be not an option. How can I proceed?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension, youtube, webdriver, browserify

My question relates to implementing the solution proposed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73453949/how-to-automatically-right-click-on-youtube-for-stats-for-nerds-using-chrome-e). The error I first get is that the webdriver is not defined. For that, I tried the [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39069396/selenium-webdriver-node-js). But at that point, I get an error that "require()" is not defined, which brought me to this [final solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined). I tried the recommended Browserify option, but I don't think it's going to work for me because I can't just throw a "script src="bundle.js"" into the html as I want to use the webdriver to open the YouTube "stats for nerds" menu every time an ad is detected to get the video ID of that ad via a Chrome extension. Not sure if this is possible. Any help would be highly appreciated. I'm new to JS.

Comment: You don't need webdriver for this. Just use the code inside quotes.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the ignorance